# What could have gone wrong with my TLP222A?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I'm using a [TLP222A](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TLP222AF/TLP222AF-ND/871243?utm_medium=email&utm_source=oce&utm_campaign=1043_OCE18RT&utm_content=productdetail_US&utm_cid=289316&so=53605919&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTVRkaE56STFOMlZpWXpNNSIsInQiOiJJejdham1BOFJRaDUzV01YcU9CaFRyV3FHOUd6MjdkQ2FMOE1nUXUxdHlFcjhPOWpQVnYwS3VkanV4YWx5cnZrck5KVVAxTFJiZ1k3d1pSMjdOYm5kSFN3ZTUrbUIyR29HK21WTGZiSllQY2FBQ1BJSENwV2NvVmRvcGl5bHNwTiJ9) to switch a 24V load that never pulls more than about 200mA. My circuit looks like this, ignore that the chip name is wrong.

[image]

I have 4 of these connected to 4 GPIO pins. 2 of them have, for no reason I can discern, stopped working. They show 1.15V at the input, which to me implies that the diode inside is conducting normally. The GPIO seems fine. But the output is floating, like the chip is broken.

I'm confident that I did not pull more than the on state current of 500mA nor anywhere near the peak 1A. I also used 220ohm resistors to supply 10mA to the diode, which is also well below its maximum rating.

Not really sure what else to look for, here. :/

Edit: as requested, [here is a link](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2700119&library=usen&pcck=P-28-04-04-01&tab=1&selectedCategory=ALL) to one of the industrial LEDs I am driving. This is the load. There are 4 of them, each on separate SSR's.

Comment: What is the load you switch? How long are the wires?

Comment: It's actually just a simple LED (it just accepts industrial voltage - 24V). I don't have a measurement on the wires handy but no more than 6-8 inches or so.

Comment: A link to the LED should be provided.

Comment: A flyback diode would not hurt, and if you plan on plugging and unplugging a lot some ESD protection would be prudent.

Comment: I think you need to check if real inrush current for this industrial "piece of engineering" is under 500 mA. I am afraid it could be 2-3A short peak that kills the weak SSR. The "500mA" was probably on AC supply, but when you hit it hard with 24 V, who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the load you switch?

> It's actually just a simple LED (it just accepts industrial voltage -
>   24V)

No it isn't.

It's an LED module that can run from AC or DC and has in all probability, a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor that has an inrush current. The data sheet states this: -

> Maximum inrush current max. 500 mA

That is right at the limit of your TLP222A's capabilities and will seriously degrade the life of that product. Toshiba say this: -

> Note: Using continuously under heavy loads (e.g. the application of
>   high temperature/current/voltage and the significant change in
>   temperature, etc.) may cause this product to decrease in the
>   reliability significantly even if the operating conditions (i.e.
>   operating temperature/current/voltage, etc.) are within the absolute
>   maximum ratings.

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue. Do I counteract this by using an SSR capable of providing 500mA under normal operating conditions?

Comment: It’s hard to think of a better alternative than a more beafier SSR.

Comment: +1 That restrictions page is rather heavy huh. "PRODUCT IS NEITHER INTENDED NOR WARRANTED FOR USE IN EQUIPMENTS OR SYSTEMS THAT REQUIRE
EXTRAORDINARILY HIGH LEVELS OF QUALITY AND/OR RELIABILITY," hmmm... define extraordinary please.

Comment: @Trevor_G - Heh. It's like the the old saying about price, "If you have to ask, you can't afford it." If you're worrying about whether a system requires an extraordinary level of reliability, you should assume that it does. Murphy's Law. Or maybe Finagle's.

Comment: Yup, you just have to wonder what lawsuit event made them decide to put that in big bold letters..

Comment: I found the CPC1002N https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ixys-integrated-circuits-division/CPC1002NTR/CLA230CT-ND/1212841 which has the same turn on voltage/current characteristics. It is also rated to work continuously at 700mA and has a 1A peak current. Does this seem an acceptable substitute?

Comment: It looks OK but it isn't an SSR I think - it's probably a single MOSFET output so be aware of this.

Comment: Won't they functionally be the same? Or is there a concept I'm missing?

Comment: They will function the same for the LED load in your question but you never said you didn’t have “other requirements” that might have justified an SSR.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you name something that would "justify" an SSR, or point me to a resource that explains when they're needed over a MOSFET?

Comment: If you were switching a load connected to an ac power source such as 24 volts AC you might consider an SSR.